# jQuery Change Nivo Control Nav Default Behavior

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nivo-slider

By default, the jQuery plugin Nivo Slider uses dots as a control navigation.  By default, clicking on these dots displays the slide it is attached to.  I need to prevent that behavior and instead, make each dot go to a url on click.  I think I need to use the `afterLoad` function but im having trouble.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery( '.theme-wcoc .nivo-controlNav a[rel="0"]' ).nivoSlider( {

afterLoad: function(){

    jQuery( '.theme-wcoc .nivo-controlNav a[rel="0"]' ).click( function( e ) {

        // Prevent default

        e.preventDefault();


    } );

}
```

} );

});

This code doesnt prevent anything.  This is the item I am working on.  http://bit.ly/YWgKo5.  Thanks in advance for any advice.